# What is the best way to keep my objects repository in selenium automation testing framework

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

My xpath value is dynamic - example - 
//label[text()=$USERNAME$] - I will replace $USERNAME$ with a value "admin1" in my tests. I may click the admin and it takes me to edit page.

Need a solution considering Memory Time of execution, reliability and performance of test.

Options
1.keep it as private static final string in each page class and have a getter method for each objects ?

2. Keep it in properties file as key value pair load the file and get value as and when required. (Create a static class with static gettermethods for each objects which inturn call a method to load the properties instance ( properties instance is not static - values will not remain in memory - I think ) and get the key value return the value as string. Close the loaded file ?
3. @findby cannot be used I think bacause my test will have different values for the same xpath ?
4. Any other options ?

Comment: you can create private method "private String getLocator(String userName)"

Comment: @VitaliyMoskalyuk both the above 1 &amp; 2 options used the method signature as you mentioned. My question is keeping it as string (my xpath value ) or keeping it in properties file which technique is effective solution interms of memory, time of execution etc..

Comment: I've moved away from dynamic xpaths completely because, as you mentioned, @FindBy does not work with them.  I agree they can be quite handy, but I much prefer the page object model using pagefactory with FindBy (the editor made me remove the extra @) and that was the price I had to pay.  There is always more than one way (well, almost always) to access a web element, so I look for an alternative way.  I find my tests are faster and more robust with the POM than they were before.

Comment: @BillHileman means create findby for each user and use them in test ? Was my understanding correct ?

Comment: No, I think you should either use an xpath to access it via it's previous sibling, or if this is a list of users create an array of elements and search that way

Comment: If you can post a segment of HTML code, I can provide you of an example of what I mean.  Place it in your original post, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all your Object Locators in Excel or JSON File.
I am keeping all my xpaths in Excel with the following Coloumns:

1. ElementName - Unique Name given to each element
2. Locator - It can contains xpath,css,className etc.
3. Type- Its like an indication for the locator for identifying its type (eg: ID,XPATH,CSS,CLASS,TEXT,NAME)
4. PageName- This is Just for Information purpose to define which page elements 
   belongs to.

For your Case  //label[text()=$USERNAME$], you don't need to define this full xpath in Excel. You have to just use TEXT type. Take reference from following example:

[Click This Image to See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxcKT.png)

And while reading locators from excel you can generate xpath 
.//*[text()='LOCATOR_VALUE_READ_FROM_REPOSITORY']